# HashChange events stop firing when an Angular ng-include exists on the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hashchange

I have the following HTML+Angular app shell that does everything I need it to do:

1. If the URL hash is empty when the page loads, it gets initialized to `#/`.
2. Whenever the URL hash changes, the `view` variable is updated.

This much works perfectly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      function Router($scope) {
        if (location.hash === "") location.hash = "#/";
        $scope.view = createView(location);
        window.addEventListener("hashchange", function (event) {
          $scope.view = createView(event.newURL);
          $scope.$apply();
        });
      }
      function createView(url) {
        var parser = document.createElement("a");
        parser.href = url.toString();
        var hash = parser.hash;
        return (hash.replace("#/", "/views/") + "/index.html").replace("//", "/");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="Router">
    Navigation:
    <a href="#/one/">one</a>
    <a href="#/two/">two</a>
    Partial: {{view}}
    <!--<div ng-include="view"></div>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Then only problem is that as soon as I uncomment the `div[ng-include]`, everything stops working. Specifically, the `hashchange` events stop firing. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Any workarounds?

Comment: any reason why you are not using the `$route` service? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route

Comment: Good question. I tried but wasn't able to get it to work for this use case. I'll accept an answer that achieves the same thing that I'm doing here but uses the `$route` service. Specifically, I want the route handler to be a function, **not** a mapping of hashes to partials and controllers via `$routeProvider.when()`.

Comment: same here... any workarounds @ChristopherJamesCalo?

Comment: I never found a workaround, @caarlos0, but I also didn't look much after posting this question. I'm not sure whether 1.2 fixes this or not.